# How to create border for png image

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I have a custom image in .png format. I want to create button. The form of button is this image. So I put the image inside button template and want it be fleshed only when mouse over the image. The shape of image is rectangle (http://prntscr.com/lz5m5q), but in fact it is custom shape. So how can I set border for button and ignore transparent background of image (I don't want see border as rectangle, border should be around my actual image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope i got correctly, is this you want ?

Style [Link](https://gist.github.com/shubdragon/3630a10bda83884a35cda8ab468ff890)

due to characters limit i am posting style in above link. copy paste codes from above link in Windows.Resources or where you want.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- I put this in windows resources you can put it app.xaml or any resource dictionary -->         
    <!-- Copy here content from the above link link because of stackoverflow character limit i cant paste it here. -->        
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Height="250" Width="300" Style="{DynamicResource CountryButtonStyle}" />    
</Grid>
```

**Output:**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what i need. Could you please advice what app you use to create Path points?

Comment: @AnastasiiaMelnyk I am using 2 ways, 1st is offline tools and other is online websites, convert png to svg through any program or use this website www.pngtosvg.com/ it render very good svg, then all you need to get wpf or uwp supported xaml using Inkspace or any other program or this on source http://harshmaurya.in/?ddownload=2520